# Using Case result for case in same statement seems not to work

Tags: sql, subquery, case

So I am just starting to work with case statements. I got to this to work perfectly without the second case (Status). In the query results there are almost always numbers in the column 'VWD'. Now I want to use a second case depending on the first one. Got the code for it on this site. Whatever I do, the column 'Status' is always (null). If I use an else for the second case, it will always use the value in else.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT f.fallid, f.fallaufndatum, f.fallentldatum, f.aufnahmeart, f.entlassart, fd.drg, k.ugvwd, k.mvwd, k.ogvwd,

    CASE
        WHEN f.fallentldatum IS NULL 
        THEN ROUND(sysdate - f.fallaufndatum, 0)
        ELSE f.fallentldatum - f.fallaufndatum
    END AS VWD,

    CASE 
        WHEN VWD = 16
        THEN 'Grün'
    END AS Status

FROM (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN fallentldatum IS NULL 
        THEN ROUND(sysdate - fallaufndatum, 0)
        ELSE fallentldatum - fallaufndatum
    END AS VWD FROM tblfall),

tblfall f
JOIN tblfalldrginfo fd
ON f.fallid = fd.fallid
JOIN katdrg k
ON fd.drg = k.code
WHERE (sysdate - f.fallaufndatum) <= 1000
AND fd.drgkatalog = k.katalog;
```

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: what is your rdbms? I think some db allow use the alias in the same query but other db dont. So you need create a subquery.

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move it into a sub-query.  This might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT  fallid, 
        fallaufndatum, 
        fallentldatum, 
        aufnahmeart,
        entlassart, 
        drg, 
        ugvwd,
        mvwd, 
        ogvwd,
        VWD,
        CASE 
            WHEN VWD = 16
            THEN 'Grün'
        END AS Status
FROM
(
    SELECT  f.fallid, 
            f.fallaufndatum, 
            f.fallentldatum, 
            f.aufnahmeart,
            f.entlassart, 
            fd.drg, 
            k.ugvwd,
            k.mvwd, 
            k.ogvwd,
            CASE
                WHEN f.fallentldatum IS NULL 
                THEN ROUND(sysdate - f.fallaufndatum, 0)
                ELSE f.fallentldatum - f.fallaufndatum
            END AS VWD
    FROM    tblfall         f
    JOIN    tblfalldrginfo  fd  ON  f.fallid = fd.fallid
    JOIN    katdrg          k   ON  fd.drg = k.code
                                AND fd.drgkatalog = k.katalog
    WHERE   (sysdate - f.fallaufndatum) <= 1000
) As X
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query doesnt know the field name because all is created at the same time. So your second case doesnt recognize VWD.

You can use Siyual option with subquery or repeat the case.

```
CASE
    WHEN f.fallentldatum IS NULL 
    THEN ROUND(sysdate - f.fallaufndatum, 0)
    ELSE f.fallentldatum - f.fallaufndatum
END AS VWD,

CASE 
    WHEN ( CASE
               WHEN f.fallentldatum IS NULL 
               THEN ROUND(sysdate - f.fallaufndatum, 0)
               ELSE f.fallentldatum - f.fallaufndatum
          END )= 16
    THEN 'Grün'
END AS Status
```